# MVC - Enabling Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have MVC 1.0 app with VS2008.

I have added configuration to web.config but the app crashes
in the Default.aspx page code behind. Dont know why its loading that page.

I am just uing all the default setup for MVC 1.0.

This is my webconfig. Shouldn't it show my login page with this config????

Malcolm

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*"
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="/Home/Index"></forms>
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

  </system.web>

  <location path="Content/Site.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default template project in ASP.NET MVC does have support for User Accounts, including Forms Authentication, creating users etc. Take a look at the template project and copy/get inspiration from their configuration file and `AccountController`.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I'd call a 'bug'... ;) But I'm glad I could help you figure it out!

Comment: I just received a downvote here, and although I do realize that this information might be outdated, the post is from almost six years (!) ago. If there is anything wrong with this answer except that it's outdated, I'd love to know...