# Asp.net generic principal problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication

Using this code for authentification:

```
HttpContext.Current.User=new GenericPrincipal
  (new GenericIdentity(user.UserName), roles);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName,false);
```

Problem is - on next request, `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` is `true`, but `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")` is false.

There are a [lot of info](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t383180-forms-auth-user-isinrole-doesnt-work.html) on google but somehow nothing helps as usual.

Tried to add this to my web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <roleManager enabled="false" />
</system.web>
```

I do not want to use membership provider.

Any tips?

Comment: What kind of role provider do you use?

Comment: *blind rabbit mode ON* sorry, i'm having a hard afternoon here :d Reflector says you're doing it right... perhaps you should double check what's in your roles string array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be trying to use the wrong kind of Identity if you're using forms authentication.  You might be better off using FormsIdentity.

[Article on Best Practices for Forms Authentication (might be outdated)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649204.aspx)

Comment: `genericIdentity` haven't property `Roles`

Comment: @Joseph my mistake. actually - I do call it on user.

Comment: @Amit ok I thought it probably was but I might have found something else anyway

Comment: @Joseph that looks promising. Overcomplicated as usual, but might actually work.

Comment: Does not help either. It does decrypt identity from cookie, set it to `HttpContext.Current.User` but inside controller action, `User.IsInRole("admin")` still is false. The same scenario as before.

Comment: @Amis What's in your HttpContext.Current.User's Roles property?

Comment: There is no `Roles` property on `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Comment: This helped - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles/2342196#2342196 Had to switch roleManager back to false in web.config and it finally works. God that was intuitive...

Comment: I hate it when something that seems like it should be so easy ends up being so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Look like the IsInRole method is on the wrong interface. Try

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")
```

Comment: Nah, that was just a typo. Didn't double check and wrote example as I remembered it. It's not solution. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsInRole doesn't even compile.