# ASP.NET MVC login controller method without using a custom membership provider?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I'm very curious as to why I need to create a custom MembershipProvider and not supposed to do something like this to login a potential user.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    UserUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UserUnitOfWork();
    User user = unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByUsername(username);

    if (user != null)
    {
        SaltedHashHelper saltHelper = new SaltedHashHelper();
        if (saltHelper.VerifyHashString(username, user.Password, user.Salt))
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, false);
    }
    else
    {
        // User cannot be verified.
    }

    return View();
}
```

If I create a custom MembershipProvider then I will have to create a custom MembershipUser because I am not using asp.net membership tables. I feel like that is more of a headache when your not using the aspnet membership tables. Maybe I am wrong.

Does anybody see anything wrong with my approach above? I'm curious.

Comment: Who said you had to create a custom membership provider?

Comment: I just got the impression that "you should" do it from everything I've seen online.

Comment: Dont use built in providers. There is an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom membership provider, you can use what ASP.NET gives you right out of the box. In fact implementing your own authentication scheme is always inadvisable if there's any other way out of it whatsoever. Worst case, just override the provider methods that you really need to behave differently.

Have a look at [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 7: Insecure Cryptographic Storage](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/06/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-7.html) for some more background on why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is fine so long properly salt and hash the passwords and properly protect yourself from SQL injection.

The built in providers will be better tested than your custom built authentication provider, and may be more secure depending on your implementation.