# ASP.NET MVC3 Role Authentication with Cookie and No SQL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, roles

I'm trying to use Roles for my forms authentication, I've got the global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest method getting the roles from the cookie, that works fine. But I don't know what provider to configure in Web.Config. I don't want to use SQL server, just the cookie.

this line creates the IPrincipal: (roles is a string array with the roles)

```
Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(Context.User.Identity, roles);
```

The end goal is to get DataAnnotations like [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] and the IsInRole method working.

Also, the IsInRole method works fine when used in the global.asax but not elsewhere. Why not?

Web.config is configured as such for now:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
```

and the DefaultProvider is sadly connected to some empty SQL db for no real reason.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Getting the roles from the cookie using the code from the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles

Comment: Turns out a bug in visual studio or something was causing the problem. The code from the post I noted above works as is, when there's nothing wrong with the web application.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative might be to use the [ASP.NET XmlProviders](http://aspnetxmlproviders.codeplex.com/).  (No Database)

Or if you just don't want to have a SQL Service Instance but want the advantages of having some type of database use [ErikJ's Sql CE MembershipProvider/RoleProviders](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/08/sql-server-compact-40-aspnet-membership.html).  (The blog mentions that CE 4.0 is not ready for production, but that was long ago, and can be used in smaller production environments now).

**UPDATE**

You could certainly role your own [AuthroizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) and override OnAuthorize on a derived authorize attribute class.

Comment: Both of these seem like an overkill to me, isn't it? I'm just trying to use the role already in the Principal. Isn't there a simple solution already in ASP.NET?

Comment: Nope.  Without a user/membership that have assigned roles, how would you know who is in what role?  I'm not a fan of recreating a wheel that works well.  I've personally used the CE version in smaller websites without issue, and get the full benefit of the providers (less working on login stuff, more work on actual client needs).

Comment: Your update might be the way to go, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Also, when I use the method IsInRole within the global.asax - it works! but it doesn't when used elsewhere. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your own provider based on what you've said. So you can read and simply set in authenticaterequest.

Now the question is where do you want to store them. How do you want to store them? Will you only set them in the cookie? Surely there is some persisted store you want to keep then in otherwise when the cookie is gone how do you refresh their roles?

Comment: I don't need a store, if the cookie expires the user is out anyway. When they log in again, they'll get a new cookie with the role data. What can I do with authenticaterequest?

Comment: When I create the cookie for the user, it has the role in it, and the Application_AuthenticateRequest retrieves it. I use the code from the second answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles

Comment: where do you store your role. how does your code know which role to add to the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the built-in role provider and specify that roles be cached in the cookie, thus you only have a single database call on login, and after that they're stored in a cookie automatically.

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
```

Comment: That's already what I'm doing, that's how my web.config looks. But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Because I'm getting 'false' for IsInRole method. and Authorize with Roles DataAnnotations doesn't work either.