# Custom Membership and Roles in MVC3 with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider, custom-membershipprovider

I use custom membership for Users and Roles in my MVC3 application.  I have custom user/roles class.  And I have the extended the RoleProvider and MembershipProvider classes for this.

I seem to have a case of roles going missing sometimes in my application and my Authorize [Roles='xyz'] attribute not working correctly and trying to redirect to Account/LogOn.  When my user logs into the application, all I do is

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (MyCustomSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
--other stuff
}
```

MyCustomSecurity.Login method basically looks up the user in the database and if valid sends a true value back.

When trying to debug the issue with my application, I came across the links below

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-27splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF
 [ASP.NET MVC Forms Authentication + Authorize Attribute + Simple Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles)

Should I also be overriding FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate() as mentioned in this link?  Or does the RoleProvider extended class take care of this?
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you use roles in AuthorizeAttribute, and roles are your own classes, so you need to override RoleProvider, especially method GetRolesForUser:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
    // put your logic to discover which roles the user has
    }
}
```

After doing that, you have to register you CustomRoleProvider in Web.Config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="%YOURNAMESPACE%.CustomRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, thank you for your response. I have done both, so I'm assuming I'm doing it right? I still seem to have problems with Forms Authentication suddenly going a 302 redirect loop on controller/methods with Authorize. What would be the best way to debug what is going on behind the scenes. Fiddler tells me the role/user cookie is still present, but there is still the 302 redirect to Account/Logon anyway. Any help would be great.

Comment: Would you know how I would debug the AuthorizeAttribute at all?