# Where and how should I assign roles to account users? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For example, I have this controller which implements the Authorize Atribute to requiere Login and be a member of Administrator Role. But I don´t know where to assign the roles to the different users. Can you help me to be more oriented? thanks!

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a very good question. You could implement this a million different ways: [Microsoft Identity with Entity Framework and Sql Server for example](http://www.asp.net/identity)

Comment: this article is for your solution https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97

Comment: one of the way of doing it is assigning the roles in FormsAuthenticationTicket..Follow this for details...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles