# Error 401 Unauthorized can't access to my home page even with the authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I had to develop a web application in ASP.NET, and I have to implement an authentication controller. You can't access the home page if you are not authenticated (obvious I know), so I wrote an annotation `[Authorize]`, only accessible if the authentication did well. But I have a 401 unauthorized error I don't understand why

Here is my code for the HomeController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace M2Link2.Controllers
{


    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Deconnexion()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My code for the ConnexionController :

```
using M2Link2.Entities;
using M2Link2.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace M2Link2.Controllers
{

    public class ConnexionController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Connexion
        public ActionResult Authentification()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Authentification(AuthentificationModel modele)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(modele.Password, true);
                    return RedirectToRoute(new { action = "index", controller = "Home" });
                }

            return View();
        }
        }
    }
```

My code for AuthentificationModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace M2Link2.Models
{
    public class AuthentificationModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Pseudo")]
        [Required]
        public String Pseudo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Mot de Passe")]
        [Required]
        public String Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Authentification.cshtml :

```
@model M2Link2.Models.AuthentificationModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Authentification";
}

<h2>Authentification</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Veuillez vous authentifier</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pseudo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pseudo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pseudo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}
```

I added that into my `web.config`

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Connexion/Authentification"/>
      </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: The authorize attribute is also something used by ASP.Net which namespace is it in? also, how is your "authentification" handled? Also, you're talking about a webapplication, but you're storing your credentials in a cookie meant for forms authentication.

Comment: My authentification handled what do you mean ? For a web application it doesn't need a forms authentification ?

Comment: I may be wrong about that though, i've just never seen it this way before. but if i look at the documentation, there's no mention of saving the password in the cookie. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie?view=netframework-4.8 here they save a cookie for a user name, i assume it's to link a token to a username.

Comment: Also, this thread may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385042/asp-net-mvc-forms-authentication-authorize-attribute-simple-roles

Answer (score 0):

Put the pseudo instead of password and change the boolean attribute of `createPersistentCookie` to false: `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(modele.Pseudo, false);`
Try it in private navigator so cookies won't be persistent.

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, bool createPersistentCookie)`sets a browser cookie to initiate the user's session. It's what keeps the user logged in each time a page is posted to the server.
`createPersistentCookie` creates a persistent cookie that doesn't expire when the browser is closed, so the user can return  to the site and be logged in automatically.